# Problem in displaying the layout when I install the apk file of the application on a remote tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, apk

I'm currently developing a small application and this week I try to installed it on a remote tablet (by using AnyDesk). So I build an apk send it by email (drive) and on transfernow. The problem is that when I download the apk file I have not the same layout that I would normally have. Some listView, TextView are missing and the Text button became black.

So like I said I try to send the apk file by using the google drive, transfernow. I also try to do the same manipulation for install the apk file on my tablet at home using also anydesk and it works (I have the good layout on my tablet). So I don't understand why on the remote one the layout is not correct.
For your information I don't known if everything was necessary but :

- I install on my tablet the same anti virus that is install on the remote one
- I also check both tablet are on same Android Version (12) and they are the same model (Lenovo tab m10 plus)
- I also activate the developer mode on the remote one

I don't known if this is a famous problem but I never had it before. I attached two screen shot one is from the remote tablet(wrong layout) and one is from my tablet.

[Remote tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmDUr.png) (wrong layout)

[My tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVUY5.png) (good layout)

Thank if your read all that !

Comment: The other tablet may have configured a different font size. This can make problems, depending on how you defined the layout.

Comment: try turning dark mode on/off

Comment: thank ganjaam your were right the dark mode was on on the remote tablet. I just didn't think of that because AnyDesk was showing me the tablet in light mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its only because the dark mode was activated on the remote tablet. Be careful AnyDesk was showing me the settings in light mode even if the tablet has the dark mode on.